# Display Text in text box according to text entered in another text box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am writing a web application in asp.net. I have two text box one field is for txtEmployeeID and the other field is for txtEmployeeName. I set the EmployeeName textbox to readonly in the Page_Load event. In my program, I have connected to my database and set up my stored procedure. What I want right now is when I typed a ID in my EmployeeID textbox, the corresponding EmployeeName textbox should displayed in the employee's name in that textbox.

For example. In my db, I have

```
employeeID: 000123 
employeeName: Jimmy
```

If I type 000123 in my txtEmployeeID, the name Jimmy will show in txtEmployeeName.

I was thinking to use JavaScript to accomplish this. This is what I was thinking but all it does is copy the text in one text box and display the same text in another textbox.

```
     function Text() {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmployeeID.ClientID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('<%= txtEmployeeName.ClientID %>').value = txt1;

     }
```

HTML Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
       <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Employee_ID") %>'
                Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeName" runat="server" CssClass="GridInput" Text='<%#Bind("Employee_Name") %>'
                 Width="90px"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Where is your database call code?

Comment: if you are getting the data from database you need to interact with database every time you press on keyboard. you can use ajax and on keyup event send request to search for a hit and then show it on the other text box

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, my database call code is in my Page_Load Event.

Comment: @guradio, that's true, I forgot JavaScript is a client side language.

Comment: @DragonBorn, solution given by `guradio` is best for you.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, thanks, I will give it a try

Comment: Your options include raising a Postback on the TextChange event for txtEmployeeID. Then pulling your value from DB and setting the Text value on the txtEmployeeName, you could use an update panel to do a partial postback if you wish. Alternatively you can look at a ajax json solution.

Comment: Please include your code in calling database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the OnTextChange event, you can do so like this;

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpEmployee" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtEmployeeID_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code behind;

```
protected void txtEmployeeID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get employee name from DB
        string employeeName = GetEmployeeName(txtEmployeeID.Text);

        //set employee name on txtEmployeeName
        txtEmployeeName.Text = employeeName;
    }
```

I'm not sure how you are connecting to your DB so unable to provide an example of getting the value.

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks for your reply. I actually have this code in my HTML page.

Comment: For Connection to DB, I have created a class to stored all my connection. Then, in my method let say GetEmployeeNameByID, I have a parameter that accept EmployeeID and return dataset. My sql query is a stored procedure.

Comment: That sounds fine, it's really just a matter of deciding if you want raise a postback event and run a server side function to get and set the value, or do it client side. The answer I provided is obviously a server side solution.